# Loop that lists folders with spaces

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, wildcards

## Approach

I have a directory with named folders, randomly, with blank spaces and periods.

I created a small loop (*in a script*) with the intention of renaming these folders.
On the basis that these are my directories (*test and empty*):

```
$ ls -la
./
../
35._JK_io/
'43A. io kl_ -'/
'Mi.Nombre.es Adios'/
```

*Note: We have tried (creo) that all the possibilities of listing and have worked at the time of differentiating  between directories and folders.*

Now, I proceeded to create a loop so that I would list only the directories and (*in the future*) rename them:

```
for archives in `sh -c 'ls -q */' sh`

do

echo  "$archives"
done
```

## Issue

The problem is that when I run the script I get:

```
35._JK_io/:
43A.
io
kl_
-/:
Mi.Nombre.es
Adios/:
```

## Question

> How do I prevent this from happening to me and to appear with spaces and as only three files?

#### Observation

When executing other scripts on the folders it has obtained that `35._JK_io /` is a directory but the other two are not

*Thank you!!*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When looping over directories, especially when these have funky names, don't loop over the output of `ls`.  In general, passing pathnames between programs needs to be done with great caution as Unix filenames may contain any characters apart from `/` and the nul character (`\0`).

Instead

```
for dirname in ./*/; do
    printf 'Directory name is "%s"\n' "$dirname"
done
```

The final `/` in the pattern `./*/` makes the pattern expand to directories only.  The `dirname` variable will get values like `./some directory name/` when doing this.  I included `./` at the start of the pattern, but you may remove this if you like. Just be aware that if you have directories that have a dash (`-`) as the first character in their names, then you would later have to use e.g. `mv -- "$dirname" "$newname"` (with the `--`) to stop `mv` from interpreting the dash in the name as a command line option. With `./` at the start of `$dirname`, the `--` is not needed.

It is *extra* important to quote variable expansions as the shell would otherwise do word splitting and filename globbing on the values.

Related:

- [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985)
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)